# How to get sidebar's content inside admin-ajax?

Tags: widgets, ajax, sidebar

I'm using a modal to display some content via an `admin-ajax` request.

Now I have problem outputting the content of a sidebar (text widgets, used for adding advertisement scripts). When I directly use `dynamic_sidebar('ads')`, it outputs the content randomly all over the modal.

What I was able to do was to use output buffering.

```
ob_start();
    dynamic_sidebar('ads');
    $ads = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

And then use `$ads` later.

Isn't there a better way to do this?

**PS :** The modal script does not support the REST-API.

Comment: I have similar issue. I want to display some advertisement dynamically on ajax page load but seems like dynamic_sidebar is not supported with ajax call. Some pointers would be nice.